# Display individual elements from array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

Been trying all morning and for the life of me I can't get individual array data to be displayed from my API. I am trying to display one body of text from an array at a time, and can only get it to output all at once. Had it working when the data was in JSON format but now its in an array I'm struggling to make it work.

My code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "API_DATA"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        let data = res.data
        this.setState({ data, loading: false });
        console.log(data)
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Loader />
    }
    // return table if loading is false
    // handling error goes with the same logic
    // table will only render if loading is false
    else 
    return (
       this.state.data.data).map((item) => (
          <>
            <p key={item.id}>{item.title}</p>
          </>
        ))
     
    
  }
}
```

I previously used added `[0]` or `[1]` etc to determine which element I wanted to display and this worked very nicely however if I try `this.state.data.data[0]).map((item) => (` It states it is not a function.

Expected output of API:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "status": "published",
            "body": "TEST1",
            "availability": "internal",
            "title": "Test1",
            "posted_by": "Tester"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "status": "published",
            "body": "TEST",
            "availability": "internal",
            "title": "TEST2",
            "posted_by": "Tester"
        },
```

Comment: you are rendering multiple react fragments one after another. not sure if it is allowed

Comment: this.state.data.data[0] is an object (first object in your array). Since its an object you cant you a map function on it. map function only available with array. if you want to iterate you can use Object.keys or Object.values.

Comment: you cant use this.state.data.data[0]).map((item) => ( because .data[0] is an object and you cant map an object.  Also did you try to wrap your mapped output between <div></div>. react generally asks you to have a parent of p,li elements